# Pandas Dataframe merge with multiple keys ("AND" or "OR"?)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, key

I need to merge two data frames. To make sure that the rows are unique I need to verify that "Name" and "Age" are BOTH matched before merging. I am using the combination as a primary key. Here is my code:

`df = pd.merge(df, df1[['Name', 'Age', 'Date']], left_on=['Name', 'Age'], right_on=['Name', 'Age'], how='left')`

When I use multiple keys ("Name" and "Age") is this an "And" or "OR" match. I want it only to merge if both "Name" and "Age" match, not if only "Name" matches or "Age" matches. I can't seem to find this in the documentation and I am getting some mixed results.

Update:
I do need to do a LEFT join for data reasons. The RIGHT table is a subset of the data I need while I need to keep all data on the LEFT. The key concept is to only merge from the RIGHT the data that matches both "Name" and "Age".

Comment: Remove, how='left' and you will get an inner join only when Name and Age match.

Comment: You need to do an `inner` join. The `left` join keeps all the keys of the left DataFrame and only the matching keys of the right DataFrame

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I do need to do a LEFT join for data reasons. The right table is a subset of the data I need while I need to keep all data on the LEFT. The key is to only merge from the right the data that matches both "Name" and "Age".

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing on this. The answer is Pandas merging on multiple keys is an "AND" function, not "OR".

Here is the test I did:

DF1 =:

```
A   B   D
----------
a   m   1
b   n   2
c   o   3
d   q   4
e   r   5
f   s   6
g   t   7
h   u   8
i   v   9
```

DF2 =:

```
Q   R   S
-----------
a   m   abc
x   n   def
c   x   hij
d   q   klm
x   r   nop
f   x   qrs
g   t   tuv
x   u   wxy
i   x   zab
```

(Replacing letters with "x" to make them not match.)

Running this merge:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Q', 'R', 'S']], left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['Q', 'R'], how='left')
```

Returns this output:

```
A  B  D    Q    R    S
--------------------------
a  m  1    a    m  abc
b  n  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
c  o  3  NaN  NaN  NaN
d  q  4    d    q  klm
e  r  5  NaN  NaN  NaN
f  s  6  NaN  NaN  NaN
g  t  7    g    t  tuv
h  u  8  NaN  NaN  NaN
i  v  9  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Information is only included from the RIGHT when BOTH keys match. Specifically when A==Q AND B==R.

Hope this can help others.